# Can't get Listview Default Separator Color

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, colors

I want to get the Color used to separate items in my Listview, this seems to be based on the Color of the Listview.

However, if I use `Listview.SeparatorColor` it returns
`[Color: A=-1, R=-1, G=-1, B=-1, Hue=-1, Saturation=-1, Luminosity=-1]`, instead of the Color.

Does anybody know how to access this Color? (I'm developing for Android only if this matters btw)

The C# Code part uses an example ItemsSource to display the SeparatorColor and produces an output. The desired output looks something like this:

`[Color: A=1, R=1, G=1, B=1, Hue=0, Saturation=0, Luminosity=1]`

Indicating that the Color is not null.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace APITests
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listView.ItemsSource = new string[]
            {
                "A", "B", "C"
            };
            var Color = listView.SeparatorColor;
            Console.WriteLine(Color);
        }
}
```

And here's the XAML Part:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="APITests.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And for the record the Separators I mean are the grey lines between the Items: [image]

I hope this helps clear up any misunderstandings.

Comment: Please explain in some more detail what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve. Currently, you're not providing enough information. You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What you're seeing is the default Color as described in the documentation of the [ListView.SeparatorColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.separatorcolor) documentation. This is correct behavior. The default color means that the color is unset, so it will fallback to a default, which is a platform specific property. You'll only be able to get that color if it was set before. What do you need this for?

Comment: I have a Lable above the Listview I'd like to separate from the Listview with the same color used to separate the Items in the Listview

Comment: So you're simply trying to figure out the current color value? You could just set the color of the Label and the SeparatorColor to the same value.

Comment: As Julian suggest, you can get the current value and then set it to your label you want like             `Color color = listView.SeparatorColor;   mylabel.TextColor = color;`

Comment: But this is precisely my problem. listView.SeparatorColor doesn't return the color.

Comment: Have you tried ewerspej suggestion? `Color myColor = ..whatever-you-want..; listView.SeparatorColor = myColor; myLabel.TextColor = myColor;`

Comment: Yes it works, I'd rather have it with the Default Color tho (it changes per device/theme settings)